# Extract log of Apex Jobs using API or any method

Tags: api

I am pretty new to Salesforce. I am looking for a way to extract the data that is on the page.

Setup->Jobs->Apex Jobs

I know you can monitor on a job that is running, but there are multiple jobs and we want to see how they are performing over time.

I want to setup an extraction to run once a day so that I can keep a history of this data in a data warehouse.

After looking around for a couple of hours I don't see anything in the API that I can use to call and get this information, am I correct?

Thanks in advance,
Gene

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can query the [AsyncApexJob](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_asyncapexjob.htm) table to get all jobs that have run over the past seven days. This includes those that have been aborted or already completed. The Status field tells you what the final result was, Extended Status gives the first error message, NumberOfErrors tells the total number of failed executions, and CompletedDate lets you know when it finished.